# dev c gave me some weird errors. I wrote some #defines put each one on a seperate line

Tags: c++, ide, compiler-errors, dev-c++

dev c++ is buggy.  I tried to compile my program. It gave my strange errors on a lines that has several define's on it.

```
11 #define VAR1 0x0001
12 #define VAR2 0x0002
13 #define VAR3 0x0004
14 #define VAR4 0x0008   
The errors said: 
line 11 column 3 [error] y does not name a type 
line 12 column 3 [error] expected unqualified-id before if
line 13 column 3 [error] expected unqualified-id before break
line 14 column 2 [error] expected declaration before } token
```

When I completely remove the lines, it still gives the errors above. So, I cut the  area and then pasted it.  I get lines of other code that are elsewhere in my program. I try to delete it, and it just doesn't delete.   Any suggestions to fix the problem?    I am stumpted :(

Comment: What precedes this code? It's not plausible that these lines are themselves the problem, it's much more likely that something before it has got it confused.

Comment: Please give lines 9 and 10 also.

Comment: My guess is a class definition in a header missing a semi-colon.

Comment: Or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: egrunin's right - specifically, you've probably already `#define`d VAR1 to be something that then makes the code invalid.  You can invoke the compile with the -E option to see preprocessed source code - it should give you some insights.

Comment: Are you using bloodshed dev C++? If so, you are using an ancient, outdated and buggy IDE/compiler suite. This is irrelevant of the error you are getting. See the [info section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info) of the [tag:dev-c++] tag. Try [Orwell Dev-C++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) if you are still using bloodshed.

Comment: I am using orwell Dev C++.   I still can not explain it.  But solution was to close the project and reopen.  Something got messed up or corrupted is all that I can tell.   Thanks for the help.

Comment: lines 9 and 10 were includes:   #include <conio.h> and #include "windows.h".

Comment: error instead of "windows.h" it was <windows.h>